# Abort any POST operation in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, post, http-verbs

My site is getting DOS attack with POST VERB, my site is a static site and I am trying to stop any POST action on the home page.

I had the URL Rewrite installed on my server, so I am trying to write rule to abort POST on homepage, but it is not working. Any other ideas to stop the POST on the homepage alone?

Thanks

```
 <rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Remove Home Page Post">
    <match url="/default.aspx" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="post" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>

</rules>
```

Comment: Change `/default.aspx` to `^default.aspx`. Anyway, you might want to consider using the [request filtering](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering) feature instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin access on IIS. 
Run=>inetmgr

Go to your site. 
Right click properties. 
Home Directory Tab.
Configuration=>.aspx => Edit
Remove POST

Then apply the changes.